# Broadcast a UDP message in LAN with fake source IP with delphi

Tags: delphi, winpcap, packets

I want to broadcast a UDP message in my LAN with fake source IP ( spoofing ) 
1. Do winpcap able to do this ?
2. Do this work on winxp, win7 ?
3. i'm using delphi, is there any good components available ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your intentions since what you want to do smells like you want to create malware (and you probably won't get help for that).

Comment: Meh. Testing framework, anyone?

Comment: @Frank Shearar: Testing what? The vigilance of the network's manager? Seriously, I can't imagine any legit use for something like this.

Comment: Actually i setup a vpn connection with my friend and we trying to play lan games to gather. But the problem is our vpn router do not support UDP broadcast and game like warcraft used udp broadcast to tell the clients it hosting game. so i was thinking to make a program listening udp and connect to another network with tcp connection, and rebroadcast the message with source ip. This may be not a good solution ... or i have to look in to encapsulate ?

Comment: @Remko: Er, testing your web service? Mocking out services you can't otherwise mock out? Handling weird network topologies that actually use your machine's network devices but without having to spend hours setting up strange cabling setups? Making sure your system can handle certain classes of attacks? Every "illegitimate" use has a use in you making sure your system works.

Comment: @Frank Shearar: of course it's possible to think of legimate purposes and just as well for the opposite. A clear description of what one wants to accomplish clarifies not only intent but also helps us to suggest better solutions.

Comment: @Remko Sure, I know where you're coming from. But do you really think a bad actor wouldn't lie to you? :) "Yes, of course this is for a pure and noble purpose!"

Comment: @Frank: only users with an uneven number are evil :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with winpcap. It should work on Windows 7 (though you may have to get a beta version of it). This is all I could find for doing it in delphi:

http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp

I don't know how well that works with the latest version of winpcap though. I'd seriously consider just doing it in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is to allow UDP broadcast in the VPN I suggest to take a look at VPN solutions that does not drop those packets such as [Hamachi](http://hamachi.cc/) or [Gamer's Internet Tunnel](http://www.morpheussoftware.net/git/) instead of creating your own solution.

Comment: Heard about Hamachi before, but haven't try it.